# react-table styled-components looses styles while loading from express js server as static app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-table

I have a react app that works standalone and it uses styled-components. I am using "styled-components", "react-table" version "^4.4.1",

The below describes what are the contents of my react production build. I don't have app.js or index.js files

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/

For production deployment, I moved it to express server and i have below express config in app.js to load the react app.

// Serve the static files from the React app

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));`

while the inline styles works fine, some of the styled-components styles don't work.

I followed below llink but doesn't know how to apply it to my app which doesn't have shared styled components and every component has its own

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components-website/blob/master/sections/advanced/server-side-rendering.md

Comment: Open up your inspector (in chrome) and you'll see what route your app is trying to hit. I would say that it's a 404 in your case?

Comment: I didn't notice any 404. All the elements are loading except some of thee styles didn't apply.

Comment: I had a similar issue with < styled components > and Gatsby - simply reinstalling < styled components > solved it.

Comment: @suuuriam are you saying its a version issue ? I have     "styled-components": "^4.4.1",